# vb.net open word document return null

Tags: vb.net

I use the following code to convert `doc` to `pdf` file, but when opening doc it returns nothing:

```
Dim wordApplication As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
Dim wordDocument As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = Nothing
Dim outputFilename As String = IIf(fileout = "", System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(filename, "pdf"), fileout)
wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(filename)
wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(outputFilename, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF, False, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument, 0, 0, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent, True, True, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, True, True, False)
```

[image: ERROR]

Answer (score 0):

There are many not defined variables in your code:
fileout,filename,outputFilename.
this is a working code

```
Dim wordApplication As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
Dim wordDocument As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = Nothing
Dim filename As String = "yourworddocument.docx"
Dim fileout As String = "yourworddocument.pdf"
wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(filename)
wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(fileout, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF, False, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument, 0, 0, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent, True, True, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, True, True, False)
```